# Plot Shown Differently in Mathematica 9 and 10.3

Tags: plotting

I try the following code to put it as a second axis in a 2-y plot as overlay but it behaves differently in Mathematica 9.0.1 and 10.3 (Numbered labels are missing in MA 10.3)

```
ListLinePlot[
Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 100}, {100}]],
PlotStyle -> Red,
ImagePadding -> 25,
Axes -> False,
Frame -> {False, False, False, True},
FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, All},
FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Red}
]
```

in 9.0.1

[image]

in 10.3

[image]

Why this happens and how can I avoid this behavior.

Comment: works with `FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}`, and this is the documented syntax, both in V9 and V10.3

Answer (score 5):

The form

```
FrameTicks -> {bottom, left, top, right}
```

was deprecated in v6 and fully removed in v10. You want to use

```
FrameTicks -> {{left, right}, {bottom, top}}
```

which is the documented form for both [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) and [`FrameStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameStyle.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works great